# How to relink files in multiple Photoshop files

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting, adobe-photoshop-elements

I saved all my linked Files of my multiple Photoshop files in a folder. I moved the linked-files folder to another place.

Now when I open a file, I need to relink it and it's not so bad. But... I have lots of photoshop files which their liked-files are moved to another place (but are all in the same folder as before) and I need to open every single file and relink it again.

##### Is there a better way to relink them all at once? (with/without Script)

Comment: Is there some easily understandable pattern like /foo/bar becomes r:\resources or something more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

**Linking Layers in multiple Photoshop files:**

- In the Layers palette, press [Ctrl] + select the layer(s) you want to
  link.
- From the Layer palette, click Link Layers. A Link icon. appears next to a layer names, indicating that the layers are linked.

Comment: Thank you, but as you can see, I've already mentioned that I can do this if I do this one by one. The question is: if there is a way to do this with a script or somehow with multiple files whithout opening them.

Comment: I believe the term "Link" in the question is referring to **placed files** which are linked to other *external files* and *not* "linking layers" together within the layers panel. **In addition**, there's no feasible way to "link layers" across multiple Photoshop files. "Linking layers" is *localized* to a single document - so your opening sentence in boldface, is actually impossible.

Comment: You are right. What I mean is linked-files, not linked layers. I have corrected my Quistion. Can you help me with the quistion?